# Proof of the Banach Fixed Point Theorem

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-verification

I am presenting to you my book's verion of the proof of the Fixed Point Theorem:

$\{T^i x_0\}$ has been shown to be a cauchy sequence. As we have a complete metric space, this cauchy sequence has a limit in the space, say $x$. So $\lim_{n\to\infty} T^n x_0=x$. Now my book presents the following argument $$Tx= T\lim_{n\to\infty} T^n x_0=\lim_{n\to\infty} T^{n+1} x_0=x$$

I'm not quite sure whether this argument is correct. What I understand from $\lim_{n\to\infty} T^n x_0=x$ is $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists N_0$ such that $d(x,T^m x_0)<\epsilon$ for $m>N_0$. Also, by notational convention, $\lim_{n\to\infty} T^n x_0=x$. Hence $T \{\lim_{n\to\infty} T^n x_0\}=T x$. I'm not sure whether $T\{\lim_{n\to\infty} T^n x_0\}=\lim_{n\to\infty} T^{n+1} x_0$. I don't think we can treat $n$ as an integer, adding $1$ to which would give me another integer. I take $\lim_{n\to\infty} T^n x_0$ as $x$, with no further scope of manipulation.

EDIT: $\lim_{n\to\infty} T^{n+1} x_0=x$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty} T^n x_0=x$. However, I feel $\lim_{n\to\infty} T^{n+1} x_0=x$ is different from saying $T\{\lim_{n\to\infty} T^{n} x_0\}=x$.
Is my understanding flawed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are many different types of fixed-point theorems; which are you referring to? It seems like the contraction-mapping theorem, is it?

Comment: If T is continuous, then it follows that $T(lim)$=$LimT$

Comment: Yes. the contraction mapping one.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty} T^n(x_0)=x$.

This means that, for any $e>0$ , there is an integer N for which:

$||T^n(x_0)-x||<e$ for any n>N.

In particular, $||T^{n+1}(x_0)-x||<e$; notice that as $n\rightarrow \infty$ , $n+1\rightarrow \infty$ also.